# How viscosity and velocity relate in a pipe?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity

Assume we have a pipe that there is a fluid stream in it. By increasing the velocity of the fluid the resistance will increase either (because of the viscosity I think). My question is how are these to parameters depending to each other and what is the formula?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pfric.html

Comment: How familiar are you with the Navier-Stokes equations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With hydrodynamics we normally find that at low shear rates the flow is limited by the viscosity of the liquid while at high shear rates it's limited by inertial forces and the viscosity doesn't matter. This is the case for flow in a pipe. At low flow rates the pressure drop $\Delta P$ is related to the flow rate $Q$ by the [Hagen-Poiseuille equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation):

$$ \Delta P = \frac{8\mu \ell}{\pi r^4} Q $$

where $\ell$ is the pipe length and $r$ is the pipe radius. So in this case the pressure drop is proportional to the viscosity $\mu$.

However at high flow rates the pressure drop is given by the [Darcy-Weisbach equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation):

$$ \Delta P = f_d \frac{\ell}{2r} \frac{\rho v^2}{2} $$

where $\rho$ is the water density, $v$ is the flow velocity and $f_D$ is a fudge factor called the Darcy friction factor. Note that in this case the pressure drop is independant of the viscosity.

At intermediate flow rates you get a complicated regime where the pressure drop has a sub-linear dependence on the viscosity.

Comment: I am experimenting with a pipette.so I think I can use the first equation.but I didn't understand how force relates velosity there?

Comment: @mahdibagheri: In the Hagen-Poiseuille equation $Q$ is the volumetric flow rate so $Q$ is related to the flow velocity $v$ by $Q = Av = \pi r^2 v$.

Comment: The viscosity is a parameter even in turbulent flow because the friction factor $f_d$ is a function of the Reynolds Number, which contains the viscosity.  The friction factor is much more than a fudge factor, and the correlation between friction factor and Reynolds Number for pipe flow is well-established.